# How to push down existing data in Excel and insert new data POI using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using org.apache.poi library to insert data in existing excel template, I would like to add from particular row no and if data is present on that line then want to push down data below the newly added rows.

[image]

this my Excel template where data is starts from row no 2

and I want to do below thing using POI java

[image]

after insert new data in Excel template

Comment: What about [Sheet.shiftRows](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#shiftRows-int-int-int-)?